# Regex for filtering strings contain any combination of upper and lowe case chars

Tags: regex

I am not too good at RegEx .

I want to query a database using RegEx. I want to get all those results that contain any uppercase or lowercase combination of my filter key wheresoever inside them.

**Example : I want to search a student table where the first name contains "lex"**

So out of Alex ; NORALEX ; AleXia ; LEXus ; Ronnit ; lent ; Lesius ; ALEx

Alex ; NORALEX ; AleXia ; LEXus and ALEx should get filtered

Comment: All databases support case insensitive query for this. No regex needed.

Comment: I am basically using a third party service for web back end and their API does not support case insensitive query

Comment: @RahulVerma Does the API support regex searches? If not, you will have to perform 2^n searches where n is the length of the string to search for: LEX, LEx, LeX, Lex, lEX, lEx, leX, lex.

Comment: Provide more details about your web API.

Comment: The api Does support Regex search :) . And the API is of Parse. www.parse.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following modifier to the beginning of you regex:

```
(?i)
```

It will result in an case insensitive mode.

The whole regex for this case:

```
(?i)(\w*lex\w*)
```

[**Online demo**](https://regex101.com/r/qV8bW5/1)